# How to use sed or awk to strip out a set of lines or block?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I'm running OSX. What command line tool could I use for this? I've got a large text file with this JSON output. I'm looking for a way to strip out only those `email`s without a `last_login_date`, where I'm not interested in the record without one. Here's the output:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52fba903e4b0aa6226e0ce26"),
        "email" : "bar@foo.com"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("521ca254e4b0d28eb6a07f26"),
        "email" : "foo@bar.com",
        "last_login_date" : ISODate("2017-04-10T14:27:03.212Z")
}
```

Is sed or awk a candidate for this? If so, can you show me how strip out from the file:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52fba903e4b0aa6226e0ce26"),
        "email" : "bar@foo.com"
}
```

Comment: [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a great CLI for parsing JSON, but note that your sample input is _not_ valid JSON.

Comment: unfortunately, that's the file output i have to work with..just seeing if there's a way to clean this. thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input were proper JSON, using third-party CLI [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) would be the right tool - see bottom.
Given that it is not, regular text-processing utilities must be used.

[neric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43329396/45375) works with the BSD `grep` that comes with macOS, but relies on a very specific file layout.

**`awk`** allows for a **more flexible solution** (still assumes that the JSON objects in the input aren't *nested*, however):

```
awk -v RS='{' '/"last_login_date"/ { print RS $0 }' file
```

- `-v RS='{'` sets `RS`, the input record separator, to `{`, which means that entire JSON-like objects are read one at a time (without the leading `{`).
- Regex-matching pattern `/"last_login_date"/` looks for substring `"last_login_date"` inside each record and only executes the associated action (`{...}`) if found.
- `print "{" $0 }` simply prints matching records with the leading `{` re-added.

---

**If the input were proper JSON**, using **[`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)** would make the processing both **more robust and succinct**:

```
jq 'select(.last_login_date)' file
```

The above simply selects (filters in) only those JSON objects in the input file that have a `last_login_date` property (whose value isn't Boolean `false`).

Answer (score 1):

If the records are exactly how you describe them, then you can use:

```
grep last_login_date -B 3 -A 1 yourFile.json > out.json
```

Basically grepping for what you interested in and keeping 3 lines before the pattern and 1 line after.